# Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range

Tags: javascript, random, integer

How can I generate random whole numbers between two specified variables in JavaScript, e.g. `x = 4` and `y = 8` would output any of `4, 5, 6, 7, 8`?

Comment: here is a useful gist: https://gist.github.com/kerimdzhanov/7529623

Comment: As a side note: for those using npm and looking for a quick, reliable and ready-made solution there's [lodash.random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.random) that can be easily required with a super small footprint (it will import just the method itself and not the whole lodash).

Comment: if it need to be crypto secure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues

Comment: Can you be *[explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1527803/edit)* in the question about the number range? In particular, zero. What about negative numbers? (*"[Texts that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) exclude zero from the natural numbers sometimes refer to the* ***natural numbers together with zero*** *as the whole numbers"*). (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: Many answers here answer some *different question* (they are not real answers). It is like some users only read *"Generating random whole numbers"* and never get to the ***"in a specific range"*** part (or even the body with the [4; 8] example).

Comment: The corresponding one for Java (102 answers, incl. deleted): *[How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/)*

Answer (score 4842, accepted):

There are some examples on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) page:

```
/**
 * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
 */
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive).
 * The value is no lower than min (or the next integer greater than min
 * if min isn't an integer) and no greater than max (or the next integer
 * lower than max if max isn't an integer).
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

---

Here's the logic behind it. It's a simple rule of three:

`Math.random()` returns a `Number` between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). So we have an interval like this:

```
[0 .................................... 1)
```

Now, we'd like a number between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive):

```
[0 .................................... 1)
[min .................................. max)
```

We can use the `Math.random` to get the correspondent in the [min, max) interval. But, first we should factor a little bit the problem by subtracting `min` from the second interval:

```
[0 .................................... 1)
[min - min ............................ max - min)
```

This gives:

```
[0 .................................... 1)
[0 .................................... max - min)
```

We may now apply `Math.random` and then calculate the correspondent. Let's choose a random number:

```
                Math.random()
                    |
[0 .................................... 1)
[0 .................................... max - min)
                    |
                    x (what we need)
```

So, in order to find `x`, we would do:

```
x = Math.random() * (max - min);
```

Don't forget to add `min` back, so that we get a number in the [min, max) interval:

```
x = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

That was the first function from MDN. The second one, returns an integer between `min` and `max`, both inclusive.

Now for getting integers, you could use `round`, `ceil` or `floor`.

You could use `Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min`, this however gives a non-even distribution. Both, `min` and `max` only have approximately half the chance to roll:

```
min...min+0.5...min+1...min+1.5   ...    max-0.5....max
└───┬───┘└────────┬───────┘└───── ... ─────┘└───┬──┘   ← Math.round()
   min          min+1                          max
```

With `max` excluded from the interval, it has an even less chance to roll than `min`.

With `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min` you have a perfectly even distribution.

```
 min...  min+1...    ...      max-1... max....   (max+1 is excluded from interval)
└───┬───┘└───┬───┘└─── ... ┘└───┬───┘└───┬───┘   ← Math.floor()
   min     min+1               max-1    max
```

You can't use `ceil()` and `-1` in that equation because `max` now had a slightly less chance to roll, but you can roll the (unwanted) `min-1` result too.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to add one to the max-min? I don't understand that part.

Comment: It's only doing that because it's calling `floor`, which rounds down.

Comment: @thezachperson31 You could use `round`, but then both, `min` and `max` only had half the chance to roll like the other numbers do. You could also substract one and take `ceil`. This however leaves the `max` number with a minimal less chance to roll due to the `[0,1)` Interval.

Comment: Is anyone getting an unusual amount of Min? I have run this many times on an integer range of [0-10] and I seem to be getting 0 an awful lot. Is it just coincidence? maybe I should use round.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle if anyone wants to test the distribution of this method: http://jsfiddle.net/F9UTG/1/

Comment: Why add 1 to (max - min)? Because the interval from min to max includes (max - min + 1) integers. Ex: min=4,max=6 means 3 values (4,5,6), not 2, because you count both endpoints. To get 4,5, or 6 equally often from Math.floor(x), which just cuts off the fractional part, you want x to be chosen randomly from an interval that starts at 4 (min) and extends to, but not incl, 7 (max+1). That x interval has a width of (max+1)-min = max-min+1 (there's your answer!) = 3, and chopping off the fractional part of 4.2 or 5.5 or 6.7 leaves you with one of your 3 desired integers, all equally likely.

Comment: If you are getting 0 allot wait a little bit... The random function uses time into its equation to give you a random number. So that could be a factor of inconsistency. I would love to see this test on a cron job through out the day with a sum of each number chosen. My reference is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: This is great except for getRandomInt() I'm showing that the max is exclusive not inclusive. If I run getRandomInt(0, 10) five thousand times I never get 10 but do get 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EvanHobbs how do you know the 5001st number would not have been 10?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Well by my figuring the probability is 1.0878630073488064e-207 of not getting a 10 if it's possible. I did it several times so it's even more unlikely

Comment: @EvanHobbs not sure what to say... it appears in my quick tests. Are you sure you're using the right function?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan ah, I see now - I thought you had copied the example directly from the mozilla developer page where the max is exclusive but it looks like you modified it slightly by adding one to make max inclusive (or they changed it after this question). thanks

Comment: I made a little page that does it for you: http://adamzerner.github.io/randomInRange/

Comment: `var randomIntRange = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;` One liner using ES6 arrow functions.

Comment: I don't understand the basic concept of this, in the basic form "random * (max - min)" with a max =10 and min = 5 will give "random * 5", surely this would return a value between 0 and 5 rather than between 5 and 10?

Comment: @JackFrost "Don't forget to add min back, so that we get a number in the [min, max) interval:"

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan thank you so much, being so dumb, the math I gave will give a value between 0 and 5 but then you add the min so it gives between 5 and 10!

Comment: @JackFrost yeah, that's right. You're not dumb, you're just learning :)

Comment: This question is old, but understanding this answer took me way too much time O.o, I think expanding math.random on next JavaScript version would be kind of useful

Comment: @SangameshDavey using [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) ?

Comment: The int one is faster if you use `return Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0;` instead of `Math.floor`. `Math.floor` is a function on an object which can be replaced and so has to be checked where as `| 0` is an operator and therefore can not be replaced and no checks needed.

Comment: Try generate a random number between 10^10 and 10^16 and see how it will fail. I wouldn't call random when the last 5 digits are padded with zeros. It gets worse as you go from 10^12 and up ... 10^12 is not even large. There are better ways to get true randomness and utilize the entire 2^53-1.

Comment: @momomo we're looking forward to your answer. Also, not sure where you've tested these, but they work fine for me.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Challenge accepted. Here are three test runs. https://hastebin.com/ikefogiyoz.lisp ... see the zeros at the end? That's because Math.random() in JS (ran in Chrome inspector) cannot guarantee more than 12 decimals ( from tests performed, could not find info online on this )

Comment: @momomo you're falling outside the range of safe numbers by using those values. I think the functions are correct given the limitations of numbers in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad, i had mistaken the 2 for 10^53. it suggest a maximum of 10^16, although my experience with random is that 10^12.

Comment: Consider the fact that on the borders it might be tricky for all: round, ceil and floor

Comment: If the question is how to generate whole numbers in a specific range, the first snippet posted should do exactly that. Now it generates floats instead. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: For anyone having a hard time understanding this, write it on a piece of paper and plug in sample numbers and see what happens.

In the getRandomInt() function, the interesting part is (max - min + 1). Take any arbitrary sequence of whole numbers from a to b. You can count the number of items in the sequence using b - a + 1. For example if you chose -12 for min and 22 for max, the number of whole numbers n where -12 <= n <= 22 is 22 - (-12) + 1 == 35. We choose a random number between 0 inclusive and 1 exclusive and multiply it by 35.

Comment: Continued from above:

We take the floor of the result, and this gives us a random number within the size of the whole number list we desire, but we don't want a number between 0 and 34, we want -22 of that, which is -22 and 12.

Comment: That's why we add min back after everything gets resolved in Math.floor().

Comment: With Crypto-Safe random routine:
function myRand(from, to) {
 let row = new Uint32Array(1);
 window.crypto.getRandomValues(row);
 return row[0] % (to - from + 1) + from;
}

Comment: it's incredibly bad form to have inclusive on the end of an int returning function.  **random int functions are ALWAYS exclusive on the end.**  (Since computers count from 0 to 9, not 1 to 10.)  if you do have a inclusive-on-the-end random into function, you MUST include "inclusive" in the name of the function.  this is universal in all languages, APIs, OS, etc.

Comment: THANK YOU for adding the .floor() and .ceil() functions to the min and max values!  I had omitted these, and was inadvertently passing strings to the function.  It turns out "6" is not the same as 6, and it yields some maddening results!  Adding floor and ceil ensure the inputs are actual numbers before performing the calculation, thus yielding the expected results.

Comment: The first code example is wrong as it **NEVER** returns the MAX range, and the second example has unnecessary `Math.ceil` & `Math.floor` on the arguments when instead you can just *WRAP* them up in a `Math.floor`. I checked Mozilla docs and it's still not updated *"Getting random number between two value"* is **INCORRECT** ~> Why is the `MAX` excluded? - It shouldn't be! **If you are allowed to take *BETWEEN* 2 and 5 apples: then you *MUST* take at minimum(*at least*) 2 & at maximum(*no more than*) 5 apples.**

Comment: Further, *no more than* does **not** mean *below*. Why would *minimum* be included but not *maximum*, then, even *minimum* has to be *excluded* if we go by the logic: *Exclude the min & max limits and keep the values **between** them*. Examples: #2: `getRandom(2,3)` **ALWAYS** returns `2` - that is a wrong logic, it isn't handling the *max-range*. A *max-range* is the **included max-*limit***. && #1: `getRandom(2,2)` returns `2` how is that for a **max-limit** that has to be excluded? And what if we excluded both **limits**:min`2` is not allowed & max`2` is not allowed? They're allowed limits!

Answer (score 652):

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
```

Comment: I know this is a VERY old answer, but using `(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) ) << 0` is faster.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Using binary operators (`x << 0`, `x | 0`, `~~x`)  instead of `Math.floor()` converts `x` into a two-complement with much smaller range than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2³²⁻¹ vs. 2⁵³), thus you have to use it with caution!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yo  I just tried your method in the console and randomly got a negative value! 

Math.randRange = (minimum, maximum) => (Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) ) << 0
Math.randRange(2,657348096152)
-1407373159

Comment: @bluejayke Because 657348096152 (1001100100001100111111111111000010011000 in binary) has 40 bits, while bitwise arithmetics use 32 bits. If you do `657348096152|0` you get 218099864 (1100111111111111000010011000 in binary).

Comment: This is a smart answer. Making the range internally [min, max+1) actually achieves the desired result of [min, max] being both inclusive. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 252):

## [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Returns an [integer random number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive) between min (**included**) and max (**included**):

```
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Or [any random number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_number_between_two_values) between min (**included**) and max (**not included**):

```
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Useful examples (integers):

```js
// 0 -> 10
const rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

// 1 -> 10
const rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

// 5 -> 20
const rand3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 5;

// -10 -> (-2)
const rand4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) - 10;

console.log(rand1);
console.log(rand2);
console.log(rand3);
console.log(rand4);
```

** And always nice to be reminded (Mozilla):

> Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random
> numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web
> Crypto API instead, and more precisely the
> window.crypto.getRandomValues() method.

Comment: If you take Math.ceil, then `+1` can be spared

Answer (score 64):

Use:

```
function getRandomizer(bottom, top) {
    return function() {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var rollDie = getRandomizer( 1, 6 );

var results = ""
for ( var i = 0; i<1000; i++ ) {
    results += rollDie() + " ";    // Make a string filled with 1000 random numbers in the range 1-6.
}
```

Breakdown:

We are returning a function (borrowing from functional programming) that when called, will return a random integer between the the values `bottom` and `top`, inclusive. We say 'inclusive' because we want to include both bottom and top in the range of numbers that can be returned. This way, `getRandomizer( 1, 6 )` will return either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

('bottom' is the lower number, and 'top' is the greater number)

```
Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom )
```

`Math.random()` returns a random double between 0 and 1, and if we multiply it by one plus the difference between `top` and `bottom`, we'll get a double somewhere between `0` and `1+b-a`.

```
Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) )
```

`Math.floor` rounds the number down to the nearest integer. So we now have all the integers between `0` and `top-bottom`. The 1 looks confusing, but it needs to be there because we are always rounding down, so the top number will never actually be reached without it. The random decimal we generate needs to be in the range `0` to `(1+top-bottom)` so we can round down and get an integer in the range `0` to `top-bottom`:

```
Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + top - bottom ) ) + bottom
```

The code in the previous example gave us an integer in the range `0` and `top-bottom`, so all we need to do now is add `bottom` to that result to get an integer in the range `bottom` and `top` inclusive. :D

---

NOTE: If you pass in a non-integer value or the greater number first you'll get undesirable behavior, but unless anyone requests it I am not going to delve into the argument checking code as it’s rather far from the intent of the original question.

Comment: I realize this is about 2½ years later, but with the input 1 and 6 your function returns values 1,2,3,4 and 5, but never a 6, as it would if it was "inclusive".

Comment: @some, It could be worse, I am 2½ years + 1 day later ^^

Comment: +1, I tested your code, it appears to create a correct value.  Creative structure to handle fixed scenarios that might be repeated a lot in the code.

Comment: Why do you have a function within a function for this?

Comment: @Alph.Dev To decouple the logic that uses the random number generator from the logic that decides exactly what random number distribution to use. When the code that uses the random number generator accepts it as a parameter (a 0-argument function that always returns a new random number) it can work with any sort of random number generator.

Comment: @Alph.Dev you can use this example to remove unnecessary code (and thus chances of bugs/errors). Instead of using `var flip1=SomeRandomFunction(0,1);var flip2=SomeRandomFunction(0,1);`, you can actually use this answer as `var coinFlip=getRandomizer(0,1); var flip1=coinFlip(); var flip2=coinFlip();` etc.

Comment: (contd.) So you don't have to provide the `0,1` parameters every time. This helps in case where you want to use the randomizing function a lot of times but the upper and lower boundaries (range) is fixed. And, you can create multiple such fixed functions from the answer above like `var coinFlip=getRandomizer(0,1); var rollDice=getRandomizer(1,6); var rollTwoDice=getRandomizer(2,12); var getRandomCardFromDeck=getRandomizer(1,52); ` and so on.

Answer (score 52):

All these solutions are using way too much firepower. You only need to call one function: [Math.random();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
Math.random() * max | 0;
```

This returns a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and max (non-inclusive).

Comment: This is so clean. Thanks!

Comment: The OP was asking about a RANGE between 4 & 8, not 8 and 0

Comment: Then it doesn't work. `Math.random() * 10 | 5` outputs only `5 | 7 | 13`

Comment: Beware: This answer is not reliable. Max: 5 & Min: 1 returns: 1, 3, 5.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the answer. People clearly have no clue what the `|` bitwise-OR operator does. As it is stated, this solution holds true for numbers between lower bound `0` and non-inclusive upper bound `max`.

Comment: Like many other answers here, this ***doesn't*** answer the question (my emphasis): *"How can I generate random whole numbers* ***between two specified variables*** *in JavaScript, e.g. x = 4 and y = 8 would output any of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?"*. In other words, a random number in a *specified [range](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/range#Noun)/[closed interval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html)* ([4; 8] in the example). Even the title says *"in a specific range"*. Read, people. Read!

Comment: @Moritz Schmidt: It may be clean, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I suspect others have suggested this (the edit queue for this answer is full and I can't approve edits) but `Math.random() * (max-min) | 0) + min` can constrain it to a range. For that, `min` is inclusive and `max` is exclusive, which (I think) is typical of random generator functions in most languages. For OP's specific question wording, you would add `1` to `max`.

Comment: bitwise is not clearly solution since it holds only selected numbers but not all since 10 | 5 holds 5 | 7 | 13 :) so wrong answer

Answer (score 43):

Return a random number between 1 and 10:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*10) + 1);
```

Return a random number between 1 and 100:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1)
```

Comment: is your "between" inclusive or exclusive? i.e. is it [1,10], [1,10), (1,10], or (1,10)?

Comment: It is partialy inclusive: [1, *)

Comment: what is the need of + 1 at the end of the function? It works perfectly I guess.

Comment: @Shachi: It is the lower bound (a badly chosen example). 4, as in the question, would be better.

Comment: 1 is too special. This will break down for other numbers, e.g., 4 and 8 as in the question (the range will (approximately) be [4;12], not [4;8]).

Comment: Can you [generalise](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22711660/edit) your answer, please (even if the literal insertion of numbers is maintained)? E.g., so it works for 4 and 8 as in the question. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 39):

```
function randomRange(min, max) {
  return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}
```

Alternative if you are using **[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#random)** you can use

```
_.random(min, max)
```

Comment: Underscore actually provides a `_.uniqueId()` function you can call for client side models.

Comment: Using binary operators (`x << 0`, `x | 0`, `~~x`)  instead of `Math.floor()` converts `x` into a two-complement with much smaller range than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2³²⁻¹ vs. 2⁵³), thus you have to use it with caution!

Answer (score 33):

If you need a variable between 0 and max, you can use:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() *  max);
```

Comment: Is max inclusive or exclusive>?

Comment: @Tree using Math.floor max is exclusive. If you want max to be inclusive you could use Math.round.

Comment: Like many other answers here, this doesn't answer the question (my emphasis): *"How can I generate random whole numbers* ***between two specified variables*** *in JavaScript, e.g. x = 4 and y = 8 would output any of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?"*. In other words, a random number in a specified *[range](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/range#Noun)/[closed interval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html)* ([4; 8] in the example). Even the title says *"in a specific range"*. This belongs in comments.

Comment: @Tree To make `max` inclusive use `(max + 1)`.  Do not use `Math.round()` as that will mess up the _random distribution_ at the ends of the range.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers don't account for the perfectly reasonable parameters of `0` and `1`. Instead you should use the `round` **instead** of `ceil` or `floor`:

```
function randomNumber(minimum, maximum){
    return Math.round( Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
}

console.log(randomNumber(0,1));  # 0 1 1 0 1 0
console.log(randomNumber(5,6));  # 5 6 6 5 5 6
console.log(randomNumber(3,-1)); # 1 3 1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: Your answer is true but I think your example is wrong.. `console.log(randomNumber(5,6));  # 9 6 6 5 7 7` Do 9 & 7 come between 5 & 6? ...... you should correct it or explain..

Comment: The last example could be considered an empty range. For example, invalid input parameters. With an *empty* result, an error thrown, or similar.

Answer (score 21):

#### Cryptographically strong

To get a [cryptographically strong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) random integer number in the range [x,y], try:

```js
let cs = (x,y) => x + (y - x + 1)*crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0]/2**32 | 0

console.log(cs(4, 8))
```

Comment: I'd recommend this

Comment: I went down a rabbit hole on this one trying to learn what cryptographically secure even meant. Ended up here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39186/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-number-generator-to-be-cryptographically-secure/39188#39188?newreg=6e4d42032f4f452f8257c311c81413bd

Comment: +1, this is the best one! However, I used `(x, y) => x + crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] % (y - x + 1)` (integer modulo rather than floating point division)

Comment: Would it be possible to get an explanation of e.g. when cryptographic strength is important and why this answer is different from the `Math.random()` ones?

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I use to generate random numbers.

```
function random(min,max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random())*(max-min+1))+min;
}
```

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). We multiply this number by the range (max-min). This results in a number between 0 (inclusive), and the range.

For example, take `random(2,5)`. We multiply the random number 0≤x<1 by the range (5-2=3), so we now have a number, x where 0≤x<3.

In order to force the function to treat both the max and min as inclusive, we add 1 to our range calculation: `Math.random()*(max-min+1)`. Now, we multiply the random number by the (5-2+1=4), resulting in an number, x, such that 0≤x<4. If we floor this calculation, we get an integer: 0≤x≤3, with an equal likelihood of each result (1/4).

Finally, we need to convert this into an integer between the requested values. Since we already have an integer between 0 and the (max-min), we can simply map the value into the correct range by adding the minimum value. In our example, we add 2 our integer between 0 and 3, resulting in an integer between 2 and 5.

Comment: As `high` is only used once, you may as well use `high-low+1` rather than have the separate increment statement.  Also, most users would expect the `low` parameter to come first.

Comment: `random(2,5)0` doesn't appear to be valid.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Syntax Error. random(2,5) works fine. What is the 0 for?

Answer (score 18):

Use this function to get random numbers in a given range:

```
function rnd(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the Microsoft .NET Implementation of the *Random* class in JavaScript—

```
var Random = (function () {
    function Random(Seed) {
        if (!Seed) {
            Seed = this.milliseconds();
        }
        this.SeedArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 56; i++)
            this.SeedArray.push(0);
        var num = (Seed == -2147483648) ? 2147483647 : Math.abs(Seed);
        var num2 = 161803398 - num;
        this.SeedArray[55] = num2;
        var num3 = 1;
        for (var i_1 = 1; i_1 < 55; i_1++) {
            var num4 = 21 * i_1 % 55;
            this.SeedArray[num4] = num3;
            num3 = num2 - num3;
            if (num3 < 0) {
                num3 += 2147483647;
            }
            num2 = this.SeedArray[num4];
        }
        for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            for (var k = 1; k < 56; k++) {
                this.SeedArray[k] -= this.SeedArray[1 + (k + 30) % 55];
                if (this.SeedArray[k] < 0) {
                    this.SeedArray[k] += 2147483647;
                }
            }
        }
        this.inext = 0;
        this.inextp = 21;
        Seed = 1;
    }

    Random.prototype.milliseconds = function () {
        var str = new Date().valueOf().toString();
        return parseInt(str.substr(str.length - 6));
    };

    Random.prototype.InternalSample = function () {
        var num = this.inext;
        var num2 = this.inextp;
        if (++num >= 56) {
            num = 1;
        }
        if (++num2 >= 56) {
            num2 = 1;
        }
        var num3 = this.SeedArray[num] - this.SeedArray[num2];
        if (num3 == 2147483647) {
            num3--;
        }
        if (num3 < 0) {
            num3 += 2147483647;
        }
        this.SeedArray[num] = num3;
        this.inext = num;
        this.inextp = num2;
        return num3;
    };

    Random.prototype.Sample = function () {
        return this.InternalSample() * 4.6566128752457969E-10;
    };

    Random.prototype.GetSampleForLargeRange = function () {
        var num = this.InternalSample();
        var flag = this.InternalSample() % 2 == 0;
        if (flag) {
            num = -num;
        }
        var num2 = num;
        num2 += 2147483646.0;
        return num2 / 4294967293.0;
    };

    Random.prototype.Next = function (minValue, maxValue) {
        if (!minValue && !maxValue)
            return this.InternalSample();
        var num = maxValue - minValue;
        if (num <= 2147483647) {
            return parseInt((this.Sample() * num + minValue).toFixed(0));
        }
        return this.GetSampleForLargeRange() * num + minValue;
    };

    Random.prototype.NextDouble = function () {
        return this.Sample();
    };

    Random.prototype.NextBytes = function (buffer) {
        for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            buffer[i] = this.InternalSample() % 256;
        }
    };
    return Random;
}());
```

**Use:**

```
var r = new Random();
var nextInt = r.Next(1, 100); // Returns an integer between range
var nextDbl = r.NextDouble(); // Returns a random decimal
```

Comment: The MS DotNet Random class is under the [Ms-RSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Initiative#Microsoft_Reference_Source_License_(Ms-RSL)) license, which means it is copyrighted. So be careful when using this derivated code, since it may form ground for copyright-infringement cases.

Answer (score 13):

I wanted to explain using an example:

**Function to generate random whole numbers in JavaScript within a range of 5 to 25**

> General Overview:
>
> (i) First convert it to the range - starting from 0.
>
> (ii) Then convert it to your desired range ( which then will be very
> easy to complete).

So basically, if you want to generate random whole numbers from 5 to 25 then:

#### First step: Converting it to range - starting from 0

Subtract "lower/minimum number" from both "max" and "min". i.e

(5-5) - (25-5)

So the range will be:

0-20  ...right?

#### Step two

Now if you want both numbers inclusive in range - i.e "both 0 and 20", the equation will be:

Mathematical equation: `Math.floor((Math.random() * 21))`

General equation: `Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min +1)))`

Now if we add subtracted/minimum number (i.e., 5) to the range - then automatically we can get range from 0 to 20 => 5 to 25

#### Step three

Now add the difference you subtracted in equation (i.e., 5) and add "Math.floor" to the whole equation:

Mathematical equation: `Math.floor((Math.random() * 21) + 5)`

General equation: `Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min +1)) + min)`

**So finally the function will be:**

```
function randomRange(min, max) {
   return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

After generating a random number using a computer program, it is still considered as a random number if the picked number is a part or the full one of the initial one. But if it was changed, then *mathematicians* do not accept it as a random number and they can call it a biased number.

But if you are developing a program for a simple task, this will not be a case to consider. But if you are developing a program to generate a random number for a valuable stuff such as lottery program, or gambling game, then your program will be *rejected* by the management if you are not consider about the above case.

So for those kind of people, here is my suggestion:

Generate a random number using `Math.random()` (say this `n`):

```
Now for [0,10) ==>  n*10 (i.e. one digit) and for[10,100) ==> n*100 (i.e., two digits) and so on. Here square bracket indicates that the boundary is inclusive and a round bracket indicates the boundary is exclusive.
```

Then remove the rest after the decimal point. (i.e., get the floor) - using Math.floor(). This can be done.

If you know how to read the random number table to pick a random number, you know the above process (multiplying by 1, 10, 100 and so on) does not violate the one that I was mentioned at the beginning (because it changes only the place of the decimal point).

Study the following example and develop it to your needs.

If you need a sample [0,9] then the floor of n*10 is your answer and if you need [0,99] then the floor of n*100 is your answer and so on.

Now let’s enter into your role:

You've asked for numbers in a specific range. (In this case you are biased among that range. By taking a number from [1,6] by roll a die, then you are biased into [1,6], but still it is a random number if and only if the die is unbiased.)

So consider your range ==> [78, 247]
number of elements of the range = 247 - 78 + 1 = 170; (since both the boundaries are inclusive).

```
/* Method 1: */
    var i = 78, j = 247, k = 170, a = [], b = [], c, d, e, f, l = 0;
    for(; i <= j; i++){ a.push(i); }
    while(l < 170){
        c = Math.random()*100; c = Math.floor(c);
        d = Math.random()*100; d = Math.floor(d);
        b.push(a[c]); e = c + d;
        if((b.length != k) && (e < k)){  b.push(a[e]); }
        l = b.length;
    }
    console.log('Method 1:');
    console.log(b);

/* Method 2: */

    var a, b, c, d = [], l = 0;
    while(l < 170){
        a = Math.random()*100; a = Math.floor(a);
        b = Math.random()*100; b = Math.floor(b);
        c = a + b;
        if(c <= 247 || c >= 78){ d.push(c); }else{ d.push(a); }
        l = d.length;
    }
    console.log('Method 2:');
    console.log(d);
```

Note: In method one, first I created an array which contains numbers that you need and then randomly put them into another array.

In method two, generate numbers randomly and check those are in the range that you need. Then put it into an array. Here I generated two random numbers and used the total of them to maximize the speed of the program by minimizing the failure rate that obtaining a useful number. However, adding generated numbers will also give some biasedness. So I would recommend my first method to generate random numbers within a specific range.

In both methods, your console will show the result (press <kbd>F12</kbd> in [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) to open the console).

Comment: "random" doesn't necessarily mean "uniformly distributed". "biased" doesn't imply "non-random". 

random means drawn from a probability distribution.

Comment: Can barely tell what this answer is trying to say.  However, if you need random numbers for uses like lottery numbers and gambling.  First you probably shouldn't be generating them on the client. Second, you need a cryptographically secure random number generator and the supplied algo is not sufficient.  Calling random repeatedly does not make the result "more random".  Author seems to be concerned about bias, but isn't providing a good algo for preventing it.  In fact, the other short answers provided produce unbiased random numbers (assuming the underlying random generator is unbiased).

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger I think what he meant is that with the "normal" algorithm [i.e. `Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1) + 1)`] the numbers 1 and 6 will necessarily be rolled fewer times than 2, 3, 4, and 5. However, the difference is basically insignificant.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function that generates a random number between min and max, both inclusive.

```js
const randomInt = (max, min) => Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Comment: How is that different from the previous answers? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works with both min and max being inclusive in the range using Math.round function.

Comment: I made the beginner mistake of posing more than one question. The capacity for more than one question is simply not there. Never ever do that. Always, always, always ***one question at a time***.

Comment: I just tried it with min=0, max=5 and got a spread of (10%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 10%). So that is the penalty to try to cheat in an inclusive range when the algorithm doesn't support it. So the `Math.round` is problematic. You would have been better of to use `Math.floor` for an exclusive range but the spread would have been equal (20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%). And then, if you wanted inclusivity you know to add 1 to the max and that is how it should be.

Answer (score 10):

```
function getRandomInt(lower, upper)
{
    //to create an even sample distribution
    return Math.floor(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)));

    //to produce an uneven sample distribution
    //return Math.round(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower)));

    //to exclude the max value from the possible values
    //return Math.floor(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower)));
}
```

To test this function, and variations of this function, save the below HTML/JavaScript to a file and open with a browser.  The code will produce a *graph* showing the distribution of one million function calls.  The code will also record the edge cases, so if the the function produces a value greater than the max, or less than the min, you.will.know.about.it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getRandomInt(lower, upper)
        {
            //to create an even sample distribution
            return Math.floor(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)));

            //to produce an uneven sample distribution
            //return Math.round(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower)));

            //to exclude the max value from the possible values
            //return Math.floor(lower + (Math.random() * (upper - lower)));
        }

        var min = -5;
        var max = 5;

        var array = new Array();

        for(var i = 0; i <= (max - min) + 2; i++) {
          array.push(0);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            var random = getRandomInt(min, max);
            array[random - min + 1]++;
        }

        var maxSample = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < max - min; i++) {
            maxSample = Math.max(maxSample, array[i]);
        }

        //create a bar graph to show the sample distribution
        var maxHeight = 500;
        for(var i = 0; i <= (max - min) + 2; i++) {
            var sampleHeight = (array[i]/maxSample) * maxHeight;

            document.write('<span style="display:inline-block;color:'+(sampleHeight == 0 ? 'black' : 'white')+';background-color:black;height:'+sampleHeight+'px">&nbsp;[' + (i + min - 1) + ']:&nbsp;'+array[i]+'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        }
        document.write('<hr/>');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

For a random integer with a range, try:

```
function random(minimum, maximum) {
  var bool = true;

  while (bool) {
    var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum + 1) + minimum);
    if (number > 20) {
      bool = true;
    } else {
      bool = false;
    }
  }

  return number;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To get a random number say between 1 and 6, first do:

```
0.5 + (Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1))
```

This multiplies a random number by 6 and then adds 0.5 to it. Next round the number to a positive integer by doing:

```
Math.round(0.5 + (Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1))
```

This round the number to the nearest whole number.

Or to make it more understandable do this:

```
var value = 0.5 + (Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1))
var roll = Math.round(value);
return roll;
```

In general, the code for doing this using variables is:

```
var value = (Min - 0.5) + (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
var roll = Math.round(value);
return roll;
```

The reason for taking away 0.5 from the minimum value is because using the minimum value alone would allow you to get an integer that was one more than your maximum value. By taking away 0.5 from the minimum value you are essentially preventing the maximum value from being rounded up.

Comment: Make sense if you're excluding **0**, then no need to "round down" range from 0 to 0.5.

Answer (score 7):

Using the following code, you can generate an array of random numbers, without repeating, in a given range.

```
function genRandomNumber(how_many_numbers, min, max) {

    // Parameters
    //
    //   how_many_numbers: How many numbers you want to
    //                     generate. For example, it is 5.
    //
    //   min (inclusive):  Minimum/low value of a range. It
    //                     must be any positive integer, but
    //                     less than max. I.e., 4.
    //
    //   max (inclusive):  Maximum value of a range. it must
    //                     be any positive integer. I.e., 50
    //
    //   Return type: array

    var random_number = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < how_many_numbers; i++) {
        var gen_num = parseInt((Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min);
        do {
            var is_exist = random_number.indexOf(gen_num);
            if (is_exist >= 0) {
                gen_num = parseInt((Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min);
            }
            else {
                random_number.push(gen_num);
                is_exist = -2;
            }
        }
        while (is_exist > -1);
    }
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = random_number;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Random whole number between lowest and highest:

```
function randomRange(low, high) {
  var range = (high-low);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
  if (random === 0) {
    random += 1;
  }
  return low + random;
}
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but something quick.

Comment: The "`+`" in "`+=`" seems to be superfluous. The parentheses in `(high-low)` seems to be superfluous.

Comment: Considering the special case (`if`), what can be said about the distribution of the random numbers?

Answer (score 6):

I found this simple method on [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools):

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
```

Comment: Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 0);  always gives 0

Comment: @madprops Because max number is exclusive. To get 0 or 1, you should set 2 as max number.

Comment: or you just add + 1 in the function that calls this method

Comment: Where did you find that? This will ***not*** output in the range *[min; max]*. For instance, if min = 3000 and max = 7000, it will (approximately) output in the range *[3000; 10000]* (not *[3000; 7000]*).

Answer (score 6):

`Math.random()` is fast and suitable for many purposes, but it's not appropriate if you need cryptographically-secure values (it's not secure), or if you need integers from a completely uniform unbiased distribution (the multiplication approach used in others answers produces certain values slightly more often than others).

In such cases, we can use `crypto.getRandomValues()` to generate secure integers, and reject any generated values that we can't map uniformly into the target range. This will be slower, but it shouldn't be significant unless you're generating extremely large numbers of values.

To clarify the biased distribution concern, consider the case where we want to generate a value between 1 and 5, but we have a random number generator that produces values between 1 and 16 (a 4-bit value). We want to have the same number of generated values mapping to each output value, but 16 does not evenly divide by 5: it leaves a remainder of 1. So we need to reject 1 of the possible generated values, and only continue when we get one of the 15 lesser values that can be uniformly mapped into our target range. Our behaviour could look like this pseudocode:

```
Generate a 4-bit integer in the range 1-16.
If we generated  1,  6, or 11 then output 1.
If we generated  2,  7, or 12 then output 2.
If we generated  3,  8, or 13 then output 3.
If we generated  4,  9, or 14 then output 4.
If we generated  5, 10, or 15 then output 5.
If we generated 16 then reject it and try again.
```

The following code uses similar logic, but generates a 32-bit integer instead, because that's the largest common integer size that can be represented by JavaScript's standard `number` type. (This could be modified to use `BigInt`s if you need a larger range.) Regardless of the chosen range, the fraction of generated values that are rejected will always be less than 0.5, so the expected number of rejections will always be less than 1.0 and usually close to 0.0; you don't need to worry about it looping forever.

```js
const randomInteger = (min, max) => {
  const range = max - min;
  const maxGeneratedValue = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  const possibleResultValues = range + 1;
  const possibleGeneratedValues = maxGeneratedValue + 1;
  const remainder = possibleGeneratedValues % possibleResultValues;
  const maxUnbiased = maxGeneratedValue - remainder;

  if (!Number.isInteger(min) || !Number.isInteger(max) ||
       max > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || min < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    throw new Error('Arguments must be safe integers.');
  } else if (range > maxGeneratedValue) {
    throw new Error(`Range of ${range} (from ${min} to ${max}) > ${maxGeneratedValue}.`);
  } else if (max < min) {
    throw new Error(`max (${max}) must be >= min (${min}).`);
  } else if (min === max) {
    return min;
  } 

  let generated;
  do {
    generated = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  } while (generated > maxUnbiased);

  return min + (generated % possibleResultValues);
};

console.log(randomInteger(-8, 8));          // -2
console.log(randomInteger(0, 0));           // 0
console.log(randomInteger(0, 0xFFFFFFFF));  // 944450079
console.log(randomInteger(-1, 0xFFFFFFFF));
// Error: Range of 4294967296 covering -1 to 4294967295 is > 4294967295.
console.log(new Array(12).fill().map(n => randomInteger(8, 12)));
// [11, 8, 8, 11, 10, 8, 8, 12, 12, 12, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Is there a difference between *crypto.getRandomValues* (used here) and *[Crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues)*?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of a JavaScript function that can generate a random number of any specified length **without using Math.random():**

```
function genRandom(length)
{
  const t1 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  var min = "1", max = "9";
  var result;
  var numLength = length;
  if (numLength != 0)
  {
     for (var i = 1; i < numLength; i++)
     {
        min = min.toString() + "0";
        max = max.toString() + "9";
     }
  }
  else
  {
     min = 0;
     max = 0;
     return;
  }

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
  {
       // Empty Loop
  }

  const t2 = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  console.log(t2);
  result = ((max - min)*t1)/t2;
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: t1/t2 always very closer to 1. and hence your function returns same number when function is called repetitively .. http://jsbin.com/xogufacera/edit?js,console

Comment: check the jsbin url.. you will see the output yourself

Comment: It works great when length is between 4-10(As I have tested on my machine), because the values of constants T1 & T2 should have appropriate distance.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the role of the time (timer/current date-time?)? What is the idea/gist? What is the purpose of the empty loop? To get some time to pass? What is some example output? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45669240/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

This is my take on a random number in a range, as in I wanted to get a random number within a range of base to exponent. E.g., base = 10, exponent = 2, gives a random number from 0 to 100, ideally, and so on.

If it helps using it, here it is:

```
// Get random number within provided base + exponent
// By Goran Biljetina --> 2012

function isEmpty(value) {
    return (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null);
}

var numSeq = new Array();

function add(num, seq) {
    var toAdd = new Object();
    toAdd.num = num;
    toAdd.seq = seq;
    numSeq[numSeq.length] = toAdd;
}

function fillNumSeq (num, seq) {
    var n;
    for(i=0; i<=seq; i++) {
        n = Math.pow(num, i);
        add(n, i);
    }
}

function getRandNum(base, exp) {
    if (isEmpty(base)) {
        console.log("Specify value for base parameter");
    }
    if (isEmpty(exp)) {
        console.log("Specify value for exponent parameter");
    }

    fillNumSeq(base, exp);

    var emax;
    var eseq;
    var nseed;
    var nspan;
    emax = (numSeq.length);
    eseq = Math.floor(Math.random()*emax) + 1;
    nseed = numSeq[eseq].num;
    nspan = Math.floor((Math.random())*(Math.random()*nseed)) + 1;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*nspan) + 1;
}

console.log(getRandNum(10, 20), numSeq);

//Testing:
//getRandNum(-10, 20);
//console.log(getRandNum(-10, 20), numSeq);
//console.log(numSeq);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            /*
                Assuming that window.crypto.getRandomValues
                is available, the real range would be from
                0 to 1,998 instead of 0 to 2,000.

                See the JavaScript documentation
                for an explanation:

                  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues
            */
            var array = new Uint8Array(2);
            window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
            console.log(array[0] + array[1]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Uint8Array creates an array filled with a number up to three digits which would be a maximum of 999. This code is very short.

Comment: (The syntax highlighting of "`Uint8Array`" is truly weird.)

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is this *window.crypto* thingy? Why is it embedded in a web page? Would it work under [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34246349/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Like many other answers here, this doesn't answer the question. It answers some other question—(my emphasis) *"How can I generate random whole numbers* ***between two specified variables*** *in JavaScript, e.g. x = 4 and y = 8 would output any of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?"*. In other words, a random number in a specified *[range](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/range#Noun)/[closed interval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html)* ([4; 8] in the example). Even the title says *"in a specific range"*.

Comment: Note that this is also wrong in another way. "which would be a maximum of 999", this is not correct, the range is from 0 up to and including 255. Adding the numbers together would also introduce bias against 255, as there is many different numbers that adds together to 255 (e.g. 36 + 219), but only two specific number that sums to 510 (255 + 255), or 0 (0 + 0).

Answer (score 2):

[Ionuț G. Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58808/ionu%C8%9B-g-stan) wrote [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range/1527820#1527820), but it was a bit too complex for me to grasp. So, I found an even simpler explanation of the same concepts at *[Math.floor( Math.random () * (max - min + 1)) + min) Explanation](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/mathfloor-mathrandom-max-min-1-min-explanation)* by Jason Anello.

**Note:** The only important thing you should know before reading Jason's explanation is a definition of "truncate". He uses that term when describing `Math.floor()`. Oxford dictionary defines "truncate" as:

> Shorten (something) by cutting off the top or end.

Answer (score 2):

This I guess, is the most simplified of all the contributions.

```js
maxNum = 8,
minNum = 4

console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum) + minNum))

console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 4) + 4))
```

This will log random numbers between 4 and 8 into the console, 4 and 8 inclusive.

Comment: This doesnt work for `maxNum = 2, minNum = 1`, the outcome is always 1. In fact, I think it's the same with any min & max that are just 1 number appart; the lower boundary is always the result.

Answer (score 2):

All of the existing answers generate a random number between some min and a max (or possibly between zero and a max) but I wanted the *most random possible whole number*.

Since `Math.random()` generates a 16 digit decimal number, the way to get maximally random positive integers is:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*10**16)
```

Answer (score 1):

A function called `randUpTo` that accepts a number and returns a random whole number between 0 and that number:

```
var randUpTo = function(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (num - 1) + 0);
};
```

A function called `randBetween` that accepts two numbers representing a range and returns a random whole number between those two numbers:

```
var randBetween = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min - 1)) + min;
};
```

A function called `randFromTill` that accepts two numbers representing a range and returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)

```
var randFromTill = function (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
```

A function called `randFromTo` that accepts two numbers representing a range and returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive):

```
var randFromTo = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
```

Comment: Beautiful, could you also note that randBetween is (exclusive) (exclusive)?

Answer (score 1):

You can you this code snippet,

```
let randomNumber = function(first, second) {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(second));
    while(number < first) {

        number = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(second));
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: There is an unnecessary duplicated line here. Just use `do - while` instead of `while`

Comment: This will be very slow if `first` is *1,000,000,000* and `second` is *1,000,000,042*. Perhaps [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56066208/edit) some caveats to your answer? Perhaps even some benchmarks to demonstrate when the performance implications become significant (to quantify it)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

My method of generating a random number between 0 and n, where n <= 10 (n excluded):

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) % n)
```

Comment: But the question was "in a specific range".

Answer (score 0):

I made this function which takes into account options like min, max, exclude (a list of ints to exclude), and seed (in case you want a seeded random generator).

```
get_random_int = function(args={})
{
    let def_args =
    {
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        exclude: false,
        seed: Math.random
    }

    args = Object.assign(def_args, args)

    let num = Math.floor(args.seed() * (args.max - args.min + 1) + args.min)

    if(args.exclude)
    {
        let diff = args.max - args.min
        let n = num

        for(let i=0; i<diff*2; i++)
        {
            if(args.exclude.includes(n))
            {
                if(n + 1 <= args.max)
                {
                    n += 1
                }

                else
                {
                    n = args.min
                }
            }

            else
            {
                num = n
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return num
}
```

It can be used like:

```
let n = get_random_int
(
    {
        min: 0,
        max: some_list.length - 1,
        exclude: [3, 6, 5],
        seed: my_seed_function
    }
)
```

Or more simply:

```
let n = get_random_int
(
    {
        min: 0,
        max: some_list.length - 1
    }
)
```

Then you can do:

```
let item = some_list[n]
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/madprops/757deb000bdec25776d5036dae58ee6e

Answer (score 0):

- *random(min, max)* generates a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
- *[Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)* rounds a number down to the nearest integer

  ```
    function generateRandomInteger(min, max) { 
        return Math.floor(random(min, max)) 
    }
  ```

So to generate a random integer between 4 and 8 inclusive, call the above function with the following arguments:

```
generateRandomInteger(4, 9)
```

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you can simply use:

```
var r = (Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1) ) << 0
```

Comment: But it will not output in the specified range, e.g. [4;8]. The offset of 4 isn't there. Can you fix it? This doesn't answer the question (my emphasis): *"How can I generate random whole numbers* ***between two specified variables*** *in JavaScript, e.g. x = 4 and y = 8 would output any of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8?"*. In other words, a random number in a specified *[range](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/range#Noun)/[closed interval](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedInterval.html)* ([4; 8] in the example). Even the title says *"in a specific range"*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's what I did.. 2 variables called `maximum` and `minimum`

Comment: No, you didn't. "minimum" must be used (effectively) as a ***pure offset*** somewhere. Here it is only used in the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example
function ourRandomRange(ourMin, ourMax) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (ourMax - ourMin + 1)) + ourMin;
}

ourRandomRange(1, 9);

// Only change code below this line.
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myMax - myMin + 1)) + myMin;
    return a; // Change this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
var myRandom = randomRange(5, 15);
```

Comment: Why *"Only change code below this line."*? It looks like something [freeCodeCamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCodeCamp) or similar would generate. Can you [clean](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59908368/edit) it up? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Using modern JavaScript + [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash):

```
const generateRandomNumbers = (max, amount) => {
  const numbers = [...Array(max).keys()];
  const randomNumbers = sampleSize(numbers, amount);

  return randomNumbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
};
```

Also, a TypeScript version:

```
const generateRandomNumbers = (max: number, amount: number) => {
  const numbers = [...Array(max).keys()];
  const randomNumbers: number[] = sampleSize(numbers, amount);

  return randomNumbers.sort((a: number, b: number) => a - b);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation works when both inputs are integers.

```
function randomRange(myMin, myMax) {
  return Math.floor(
    Math.random() * (Math.ceil(myMax) - Math.floor(myMin) + 1) + myMin
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function randomNumbersWithIn(min, max, howMany) {    
    const totalNums = max - min + 1    
    const randomNums = []
    while(randomNums.length <= howMany) {
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    if(randomNums.includes(num)) {
        continue
    }
    totalNums.push(num)
    }
    return randomNums.sort()
}
```

not an efficient solution though. excluded boundary checks.

Answer (score -3):

#### Problems with the accepted answer

It's worth noting that [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range/1527820#1527820) does not properly handle cases where *min* is greater than *max*. Here's an example of that:

```js
min = Math.ceil(2);
max = Math.floor(1);
for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
}
```

In addition, it's a bit wordy and unclear to read if you're unfamiliar with this little algorithm.

#### Why is Randojs a better solution?

Randojs handles cases where min is greater than max automatically (and it's cryptographically secure):

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) console.log(rando(2, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

It also handles negatives, zeros, and everything else you'd expect. If you need to do floats or use other variable types, there are options for that as well, but I won't talk about them here. They're on the [site](https://randojs.com) so you can delve deeper there if needed. The final reason is pretty obvious. Stylistically, it's is much cleaner and easier to read.

---

#### TL;DR. Just give me the solution...

[randojs.com](https://randojs.com) makes this and a ton of other common randomness stuff robust, reliable, as simple/readable as this:

```js
console.log(rando(20, 30));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using a library for this kind of problem is too much. The point here is to understand / learn how to do it, not blackboxing the problem solving through a library.

Comment: They are now on version 2.0.0 - Although I'm not sure whether this is an LTS version, I'm going to wait till I know for sure before I upgrade 

Comment: They also have an `npm` package I believe

Comment: Version 2.0.0 is the standard version now. Version 1.0.0 is a rarely used version for people that prefer Math.random()-based computation over cryptographically secure results. It's safe to upgrade if that's your preference!

Answer (score -3):

Here's something I found on a webpage:

```js
function randomInt(e,t){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(t-e+1)+e)}
```