# Random Number Generator is always generating the same numbers

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to fill my array with random numbers using the following piece of code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

int main(){
int n = 5;
int list[10];
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 eng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 1000);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    list[i] = distr(eng);

std::cout<<"The list of elements is: ";
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    std::cout<<list[i]<<" ";
}
```

For n = 5, I always get the same output

```
562 726 348 916 6
```

For n = 6, I always get the same output

```
562 726 348 916 6 594
```

These numbers arent random, I also checked the entropy

```
std:cout<<rd.entropy();
```

This gives me the output

```
0
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get random numbers in my array?

Comment: You might want to include what compiler and version you are using and what platform you are on. Your code works for me in VS2013.

Comment: It also works for me with GCC and ArchLinux ...

Comment: you need to declar srand(time(NULL))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, twenty numbers not random?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159490/c-twenty-numbers-not-random)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, that post is about `srand`, but this one is about `random_device`. The latter should produce better randomness.

Comment: I had the same problem with g++ libraries in Windows. You can use <chrono> functions to seed the deterministic generator like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34682790/4944425).

Comment: @FirstStep: No, `srand()` is the seed for `rand()`, which is obsolete.

Comment: @Msalters I didn't understand. Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 3):

Call the [`entropy()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy) on `std::random_device` to find out whether your implementation implements it properly:

> std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an
>   implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a
>   non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to
>   the implementation. In this case each std::random_device object may
>   generate the same number sequence.

([Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device))

If this is the case, a [call to `entropy()` will return `0`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy):

> A deterministic random number generator (e.g. a pseudo-random engine)
>   has entropy zero.

If that is the case, you need to use a different fallback mechanism for seeding. For instance, you could use a time-based seed like in the old C-days.

On desktop platforms in particular, you should expect `std::random_device` to be implemented as a proper non-deterministic source though. If this is not the case, you might just be using a very old version of the standard library implementation. If you have the feeling that the implementation should support non-deterministic `std::random_device` but it does not, consider filing a bug report with your standard library maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

If a random hardware device is not available to the implementation, a pseudo random number engine is used. Is a random number hardware device available? By that, I mean not only physically there, but also available to that particular implementation of std::random_device.