# Does Ruby on Linux use /dev/random?

Tags: ruby, linux, random

I am creating a [pastebin app](http://voidptr.heroku.com/) and I want the pastes' IDs to be truly random. `/dev/random` on Linux (hosted on a Linux machine) uses noise so it's output is truly random.

Currently I use this code to generate the IDs:

```
self.guid = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Time.new.to_s + (0...50).map{ ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join)
```

Does Ruby's `rand` function use `/dev/random`, and if not how can I use `/dev/random` in Ruby? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hardly [documented](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom) SecureRandom (standard lib in ruby 1.9.2) uses OpenSSL (which is faster than urandom), if not available it uses urandom, last it checks if win32's random is
available. If none you'll get an error.
It has nice features:

```
require 'securerandom'
puts SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(50)
#=> thgv48AT_gGcYD3xx-lCqRWjoAFqN3pm2ZBKOZPZP2BC0aSMD5rXg1EaPzKLbJMMt4Y
puts SecureRandom.uuid
#=> 2670f82a-0aee-41a8-93c5-2d08e2c608db
```

([uuid: RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt))

Comment: Please note that [/dev/random is not /dev/urandom](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001388) mentions a Mersenne twister, implying a software solution, not the random device.

However, it *might* use a device for seeding, depending on the version of Ruby that you are using and how it was compiled.  A quick grep of the ruby-1.9.2-p0 source shows a few references to `/dev/urandom` (perhaps for OpenSolaris) which looks like that device will be used for seeding if the `USE_DEV_URANDOM` macro is defined.

You are better off reading from `/dev/random` directly if you really need that degree of randomness.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572366/how-to-use-dev-random-or-urandom-in-c) should get you started.