# How to use function srand() with time.h?

Tags: c, random, srand

My program contains code that should generate a random positive integer number every time I execute it. It generates random numbers but only once. After that, when I execute same code, it gives me same values, and it is making my code useless.

I started with the **rand** function, and then I used the **srand()** function with the **time.h** header file, but still it is not working properly.

```
#define size 10
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    Arr[i] = rand()%size;
```

First call (random):

```
6 0 2 0 6 7 5 5 8 6
```

Second call (random but same as previous):

```
6 0 2 0 6 7 5 5 8 6
```

---

Later I visited Stack Overflow questions and I read about the srand() function, and I used it as:

```
#include<time.h>
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    Arr[i] = srand(time(NULL));
```

**First call:**

```
-10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327 -10327
```

**Second call:**

```
-10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326 -10326
```

It is giving me different (but not random values). I've defined **Arr[i] as unsigned int**, and still I am getting negative values.

Comment: did you set your seed?  Set your seed with the time function.

Comment: You only need to call `srand` once to seed the `rand` generator.  Don't call `srand` each time to get your numbers

Comment: You probably ought to read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), which explains how these functions work, and provides a working example.

Comment: @Magn3s1um I don't know what you are talking about

Comment: You set your seed with the current time: srand(time(null)).  Then you call rand.  That way you get a unique seed every single time.  The seed changes the random algorithm.  Do you understand now?

Comment: is there any specific reason for using srand(), if not may be you can follow [**How to use /dev/random or urandom in C? stackoverflow** ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572366/how-to-use-dev-random-or-urandom-in-c)

Comment: @Magn3s1um: Clear and concise explanation :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to call `srand()` *once*, to randomize the seed, and then call `rand()` in your loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define size 10

srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed

for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    Arr[i] = rand()%size;
```

Comment: srand() takes an unsigned int as an input, so time(NULL) should be recast.

Answer (score 4):

Try to call randomize() before rand() to initialize random generator.

(look at: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once))

Comment: Please write me the code, it would be really helpful if you put it

Comment: `randomize` is not a standard function - perhaps you mean `srand` ?

Comment: Paul R, yes, i mean srand() from the "stdlib.h". Thank you for adding comment. My mistake.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/ has an example where srand is called more than once.

Comment: That example is to illustrate that not calling `srand()` has the same effect as calling `srand(1)`. It should be made clearer, though.

Comment: @Ðeepak, may this information will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

If you chose to `srand`, it is a good idea to then call `rand()` at least once before you use it, because it is a kind of horrible primitive psuedo-random generator. See Stack Overflow question *[Why does rand() % 7 always return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866754/objective-c-c-why-does-rand-7-always-return-0)*.

```
srand(time(NULL));
rand();
//Now use rand()
```

If available, either `random` or `arc4rand` would be better.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"conio.h"
#include"time.h"

void main()
{
  time_t t;
  int i;
  srand(time(&t));

  for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    printf("%c\t",rand()%10);
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include"stdio.h"//rmv coding for randam number access

#include"conio.h"

#include"time.h"

void main()
{
    time_t t;
    int rmvivek;

    srand(time(&t));
    rmvivek=1;

    while(rmvivek<=5)
    {
        printf("%c\t",rand()%10);
        rmvivek++;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: this method encryption and decryption progamming used subpart