# How can I fill file with 100 mb data from /dev/urandom?

Tags: c, linux

I'm new to Linux system programming.
How can I fill some file with 100 mb of any data (but not zeros)?
The only way I see is to use /dev/urandom, but how to do this?
I know there's `dd` command in Shell, but I'm writing a C program

Comment: `fopen` the file an `fread` bytes.

Comment: sorry just read that you want to do that fro C. You can invoke the dd from C: "dd if=/dev/urandom of="sample.txt bs=100M count=1"" with system or fork

Comment: If you don't want to use `dd`, look for the source of any file-copying program (there are plenty of those), then modify it to stop after it has copied a certain amount of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call will fill a buffer `buf` with at most `count` bytes, and return the actual size that was filled. So what you need to do is just:

1. 3 = open() /dev/urandom
2. 4 = open() target file
3. read() in a buffer from 3 and write into 4 until written size equals 100*1024*1024
4. close(3)
5. close(4)

and you're done. You can also optimize using mmap() for instance, but it may not worth it.

Comment: What is 3 and 4? File descriptors? Could you please explain with just a little of code?

Comment: Yeah 3 and 4 are file descriptors returned by `open()`, used to read / write and close.

Comment: And last question: how big should be buffer? I'm quite a noob, so I think, that 1 megabyte of buffer is normal. Is it right? Or I must use much smaller one?

Comment: I think above psudo code implemented partially here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572366/how-to-use-dev-random-or-urandom-in-c

Comment: You should avoid a big buffer, because I would consume a lot of memory for that process. I think 100k buffer is a fair trade.