# Security of random number generation in c

Tags: c, security, cryptography

It want to use a random number generator in security application such cryptography.

I know that `srand(time(NULL))` can be used to generate random numbers at run time.

Is there a more secure implementation of a secure random number generator in the C standard library?

Comment: On recent Linux distributions, the `getrandom` system call can be used to get crypto-secure random numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2572373/646887

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39475626/6850771

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/822368/6850771

Comment: Note that you could use any *external* secure random number generator to **seed** an *internal* DRBG (or CSPRNG), i.e. a deterministic random number generator. That's often very secure *and* very speedy. You may want to use a library routine or open source implementation for that though.