# how to fill, shuffle, deal the card game

Tags: c

I some how got it working but I still have  a problem with the sorting and making pairs so that I can determine the winner.

Pair them(Pairs are cards with the same value.)e.g Ace of Hearts & Ace of Spades make a pair.
I then count those pairs. hand with highest pairs wins.

This was what I was trying for the pairing but.. am still rellyy stuck with how I start the comparison to make the pairing.

This is the way I expect the results to be for every hand:

Hand 1:
Six of Spades, is Black
Seven of Diamonds, is Red
Eight of Spades, is Black
Ten of Hearts, is Red
Queen of Spades, is Black
Number of pairs: 0

Hand 2:
Three of Spades, is Black
Five of Diamonds, is Red
Five of Clubs, is Black
Nine of Diamonds, is Red
Queen of Diamonds, is Red
Number of pairs: 1
Highest pair is: Five

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <time.h>

    struct card { 
      const char *face;
     const char *suit;
        const char *color;
         };

       typedef struct card Card;
       typedef unsigned char pairs;

        void fillDeck( Card * const, const char *[], const char *[] ,const char *[]);
        void shuffle( Card * const );
     void print( const Card * const );
     pairs findpairs(card *hand);  /* finds any pairs in a hand */

  int main()
   {
     int hand,cd,winner;
     card hands[5][5],handssorted[5][5];
      pairs numpairs[5],highest;
      Card deck[52];
       const char *face[] = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five","Six", "Seven",
                              "Eight", "Nine", "Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"};
       const char *suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
       const char *color[]= {"Black","Red"};
       srand( time( NULL ) );
       fillDeck( deck, face, suit, color );
       print( deck );
       printf("\n ----------------------------------------------------------           \n");
       shuffle( deck );
       print( deck );
       for(cd=0;cd<5;cd++)
    {

    }

   for(hand=0;hand<5;hand++)
    {
        /* sort the hands here */
        numpairs[hand]=findpairs(handssorted[hand]);
        printf("Hand %i:\n",hand+1);
        /* print the hands here */
        /* print the number and value of any pairs here */
   }

   /* determine the winner and print it */
     system("pause");
     return 0;

  }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------         void fillDeck( Card * const wDeck, const char * wFace[], const char * wSuit[],  
     const char * wColor[])
     {
       int i;
       for ( i = 0; i <= 51; i++ ) { 
          wDeck[i].face  = wFace[ i % 13 ];
          wDeck[i].suit  = wSuit[ i / 13 ];
          wDeck[i].color = wColor[i%2];
      //    if ()
             //           wDeck[i].suit = wSuit[ i / 13 ];
              }
         }
       //------------------------------------------------------------------
       void shuffle( Card * const wDeck )
            {
       int i, j;
       Card temp;
       for ( i = 0; i <= 51; i++ ) { 
          j = rand() % 52;
          temp = wDeck[ i ];
          wDeck[ i ] = wDeck[ j ];
          wDeck[ j ] = temp;
             }
        }
    //---------------------------------
     void print( const Card * const wDeck )
     {
       int i;
       for ( i = 0; i <= 51; i++ ){
          printf( "\t%s\t of \t%-8s is \t%s \n \t", wDeck[i].face, 
                  wDeck[i].suit,wDeck[i].color,
                 ( i + 1 ) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n' );}
        }
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
          pairs findpairs(card *hand)
           {
            pairs numpairs=0;  
            for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ){
            if (hand[i].face == )

             }

      return numpairs;

        }
```

Comment: Suit and colour are not independent.

Comment: Please learn how to format your post correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You told us the expected results, but not what are the actual results.

Comment: Is this your complete code?  What is `handssorted`?  And "Black Seven of Diamonds", "Red Eight of Spades", etc. don't make sense.

Comment: i would suggest you abstract one more level i.e. CardDeck then have methods on the CardDeck to initialize and shuffle the cards etc. also better to use std::string instead of pointers to the strings with card names etc.

Answer (score 1):

- You have a call to `print(deck)` in there immediately after `srand()` which uses the uninitialised `deck` array.
- `numpairs`, `findpairs`, and `handssorted` are undefined
- you are printing the entire `deck` for each hand. Is that really what you intend?
- `onst` is not valid (presumably you meant `const`)
- `fillDeck()` is not filling in the `.color` member of each `Card`
- your shuffle algorithm is suspect. See [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)
- in `print()`, you are using the `%c` format specifier with a `const char *` type

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question (I'm not actually sure what you're asking), but I will point out that your shuffling algorithm is not random.

First, using `%` to limit `rand` to a range of values is usually a bad idea. (See [Q13.16 from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html).)

Second, it looks like you might be trying to implement the [Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but your implementation is wrong.  It's easy to see that your approach of swapping with previously-swapped elements is problematic; consider shuffling a deck of three elements { 0, 1, 2 }:

```
First iteration     Second iteration
------------------------------------
{ 0, 1, 2 }         { 1, 0, 2 }
                    { 0, 1, 2 }
                    { 0, 2, 1 }
------------------------------------
{ 1, 0, 2 }         { 0, 1, 2 }
                    { 1, 0, 2 }
                    { 1, 2, 0 }
------------------------------------
{ 2, 1, 0 }         { 1, 2, 0 }
                    { 2, 1, 0 }
                    { 2, 0, 1 }
```

The first column represents the possible states of the deck after the first iteration (where you swap `deck[0]` with `deck[rand() % 3]`).

The second column represents the possible states of the deck after the second iteration (where you swap `deck[1]` with `deck[rand() % 3]`).

There are 9 equally probable states---but this is obviously wrong since there should be only 3! = 6 permutations.  And indeed, several states are duplicated, which means that they have a higher probability of occurring. (Note that even if I had proceeded to the third iteration, you'd end up with 27 states for only 6 permutations, and since 27 is not divisible by 6, you'd clearly end up with some states occurring more than others.)

Answer (score 0):

> This is the way I expect the results to be for every hand

Then assign statically to the hands the desired cards. In your model every card has already unique number from 0 to 51. If deck and hand are both set of numbers then the operation is as simple as removing number from one set and adding it to another.

You might want to implement functions to work with such `int` sets, representing deck, hands, etc.

> j = rand() % 52;

If you are serious into making a game, you might want to check [how to generate random numbers from a range too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range).