# Adjusting XORShift generator to return a number within a maximum

Tags: java, performance, random

I need to generate random integers within a maximum. Since **performance is critical**, I decided to use a XORShift generator instead of Java's Random class.

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
seed ^= (seed << 21);
seed ^= (seed >>> 35);
seed ^= (seed << 4);
```

This implementation <sub>[(source)](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/xorshift.shtml)</sub> gives me a long integer, but what I really want is an integer between 0 and a maximum.

```
public int random(int max){ /*...*/}
```

What it is the most efficient way to implement this method?

Comment: Can't you just modulo the long by the maximum?

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal This produces a (slight) bias for some integers (of course, may be negligible if max is sufficiently small).

Comment: If performance is critical, you should avoid `nanoTime()`.

Comment: If performance is critical, you should probably use a simple LCG instead. If max is constant and known ahead of time, you could even build an ad-hoc LCG that will directly generate numbers in the range [0, max) with no bias.

Comment: Performance shouldn't be a consideration when using XORShift; the fact that you're using it means that it's for a non-critical application which means System.nanoTime() is perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had some fun with your code and came up with this:

```
public class XORShiftRandom {

private long last;
private long inc;

public XORShiftRandom() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public XORShiftRandom(long seed) {
    this.last = seed | 1;
    inc = seed;
}

public int nextInt(int max) {
    last ^= (last << 21);
    last ^= (last >>> 35);
    last ^= (last << 4);
    inc += 123456789123456789L;
    int out = (int) ((last+inc) % max);     
    return (out < 0) ? -out : out;
}

}
```

I did a simple test and it is about **Four** times as fast as the `java.util.Random`

If you are intrested in how it works you can read this [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper):

Disclamer:

> The code above is designed to be used for research only, and not as a
>   replacement to the stock Random or SecureRandom.

Comment: Any explanation for the shift values of 21, 35, 4? Namely, did you test with other values for speed and/or randomness?

Comment: These values come from the OP, i did not play with them. Maybe ask the Question to him.

Comment: A quick discussion of why those values are of use is found here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/xorshift.shtml#.V0Yb5nUrKkA

Comment: Note that (unlike `java.util.Random`) your results are not exactly uniformly distributed. They can't be as `2**32` (the number of ints) is not divisible by `max`, except for powers of two. For really big `max` like `3e9`, the ratio is 1:2, for small values, it's much better.

Comment: @maaartinus, thats why i did also put the disclaimer... it can indeed be further improved, but that is for who ever decides to use it.

Comment: @maaartinus I think this is a very important point that shouldn't be underplayed. I interpreted the requirement as being to find a performance-efficient method to scale the result to a desired range without compromising the uniform-distribution property of the original algorithm. Taking a modulus does not fulfill this.

Comment: I would suggest using the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196060/2568535

Comment: @TerryBurton This may loop close to forever. For a simple fix, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Seeding

There are many problems here. In case, you're using `nanoTime` more than once, you'd definitely doing it wrong as `nanoTime` is slow (hundreds of nanoseconds). Moreover, doing this probably leads to bad quality.

So let's assume, you seed your generator just once.

## Uniformity

If care about uniformity, then there are at least two problems:

### Xorshift

It never generates zero (unless you unlucky with seeding and then zero is all you ever get).

This is easily solvable by something as simple as

```
private long nextLong() {
    x ^= x << 21;
    x ^= x >>> 35;
    x ^= x << 4;
    y += 123456789123456789L;
    return x + y;
}
```

The used constant is pretty arbitrary, except for it must be odd. For best results, it should be big (so that all bits change often), it should have many bit transitions (occurrences of `10` and `01` in the binary representation) and it shouldn't be too regular (`0x55...55` is bad).

However, with `x!=0` and any odd constant, uniformity is guaranteed and the period of the generator is `2**64 * (2*64-1)`.

I'd suggest seeding like

```
seed = System.nanoTime();
x = seed | 1;
y = seed;
```

### nextInt(int limit)

The accepted answer provides non-uniformly distributed values for the reason I mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213395/adjusting-xorshift-generator-to-return-a-number-within-a-maximum/13533895?noredirect=1#comment78671130_13533895). Doing it right is a bit complicated, you can copy the code from `Random#nextInt` or you can try something like this (untested):

```
public int nextInt(int limit) {
    checkArgument(limit > 0);
    int mask = -1 >>> Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(limit);
    while (true) {
        int result = (int) nextLong() & mask;
        if (result < limit) return result;
    }
}
```

Above, the `mask` looks in binary like `0...01...1`, where the highest one corresponds with the highest one of `limit`. Using it, a uniformly distributed number in the range `0..mask` gets produced (unifomrnity is easy as `mask+1` is a power of two). The conditional refuses numbers not below `limit`. As `limit > mask/2`, this happens with a probability below 50%, and therefore the expected number of iterations is below 2.

## Recommendation

Fooling around with this is fun, but testing it is hard and I'd recommend using `ThreadLocalRandom` instead, unless you need reproducibility.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for taking time to respond with the basis for a solid approach!