# Random number c++ in some range

Tags: c++, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Generate Random numbers uniformly over entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)

I want to generate the random number in c++ with in some range let say i want to have number between 25 and 63.

How can I have that?

Comment: this works perfectly even with loops:
output = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1))

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the random functionality included within the additions to the standard library (TR1). Or you can use the same old technique that works in plain C:

```
25 + ( std::rand() % ( 63 - 25 + 1 ) )
```

Comment: Note that this answer *does not generate equally-likely numbers!*  The below answer is a better approach.

Comment: @GeorgeHilliard why? i really does not know, how the algorithm for generating random numbers work

Comment: @milanHrabos an example will easily make that clear: `std::rand()` returns equally distributed integers from `0` to `RAND_MAX` (*inclusively*). Now, assuming you obtained integers in the range from `0` to `RAND_MAX - 1` (inclusively) by using `std::rand() % RAND_MAX`, the chance of getting a `0` would now be doubled, since it will be the result when `std::rand()` returns *either* `0` *or* `RAND_MAX`. Any other number will only be obtained when directly returned by `std::rand()`. This will apply similarly, for every modulo that is not a divisor of `RAND_MAX + 1`.

Comment: @GeorgeHilliard "Below" is relative.

Answer (score 363):

Since nobody posted the modern C++ approach yet,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(25, 63); // define the range

    for(int n=0; n<40; ++n)
        std::cout << distr(gen) << ' '; // generate numbers
}
```

Comment: If you wonder "what the hack is `mt19937` type?!" - `A Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator of 32-bit numbers with a state size of 19937 bits.` It is a "wrapper" for the "mersenne_twister_engine" template (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/) with pre-set params.

Comment: I made a little I/O console app that asks for info and then dynamicly outputs the random numbers acordingly - http://ideone.com/wk239Q *BTW: modern C++ approach - +♥ ! *

Comment: Downvote for the moment, as `std::random_device` returns the error `/home/akiva/Programming/Tutorial/tutorial/main.cpp:21: error: 'random_device' is not a member of 'std'` in my ubuntu 14.10 setup with qtcreator. Not sure if this a deprecated function, that it is not included in Linux, or if I am simply incompetent.

Comment: @Akiva I think, the last is correct. If it's absent from your distribution, you should upgrade your compiler to C++11-compliant one. It isn't a deprecated function, it's a new one. GCC 4.9+ should certainly have it.

Comment: Also worth noting that to do this same thing with floats/doubles, one can use std::uniform_real_distribution<>. Great answer!

Comment: Note the `std::uniform_int_distribution<>` is inclusive -- `[25,63]` in the above example.

Comment: @Akiva and @polkovnikov.ph: It's not about upgrading the compiler (GCC has had C++11 support for ages), but about switching to C++11 using the `-std=c++11` compiler flag. Since C++11 is not backwards compatible, all standard-complying compilers (GCC, clang,...) require C++11 to be activated explicitly.

Comment: could anybody explain how to put this stuff into class members without template overblowing and simply reuse the number generation on any place, like a loop or a callback function? [Here](https://cppbyexample.com/random_int.html) is a ref but only with globals

Comment: Thanks though it is incredible the hops one has to jump just to get a random integer in C++ in this day and age

Comment: @gatopeich that's why there's a proposal for https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint

Answer (score 35):

```
int range = max - min + 1;
int num = rand() % range + min;
```

Comment: Bad advice. This will not yield a uniform distribution. It is a fairly common approach though (but fundamentally flawed).

Comment: Why is this flawed? If `rand() % range` is relatively uniform, I would expect that adding a constant would preserve uniformity. Or are you saying that `rand()` itself isn't a great choice for a truly random number? That's true, but depending on what OP wants to do, rand() may be sufficient.

Comment: @Johannes: I think [this is uniform enough](http://ideone.com/y6m8o) for most peoples purposes unless they specifically mention perfect uniformity as a requirement.

Comment: adding a constant will not preserve uniformity when range is large.  However, for most applications this is uniform enough.

Comment: @Anson: The reason that `Johannes Rudolph` is complaining is that % does not work unless the value on the right is an exact divisor of RAND_MAX. If it is not then some values have a slight (very slight) smaller probability. example: RAND_MAX (32767) `r = rand()%3;` Probability of 0(10923/32767) 1(10922/32767) 2(10922/32767) Notice the probability of a 0 is slightly higher. As 'Benjamin Lindley' points out this is insignificant in most situations but when you do things like cryptography things like this become a problem. Thus a lot of people cry foul when this method is used.

Comment: Also there was a problem with the bottom few bits of rand() not being very random (thus if max-min is small you don't get good values (this may have been fixed)). The alternative being `num = rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX * (max-min+1) + min;`

Comment: @MartinYork your alternative is no better, it still suffers from the pigeonhole problem, it's just not as obvious why.

Answer (score 31):

```
int random(int min, int max) //range : [min, max]
{
   static bool first = true;
   if (first) 
   {  
      srand( time(NULL) ); //seeding for the first time only!
      first = false;
   }
   return min + rand() % (( max + 1 ) - min);
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit, I'm pretty sure that was your intent.

Comment: For this to be inclusive of max you have to use max - min + 1

Comment: Does it include a range between negative to positive?

Comment: Use "return min + rand() % (max + 1 - min);" to obtain the max value itself! =D

Comment: rand() returns only numbers in band [0;RAND_MAX]. If (max - min) > RAND_MAX, you never got numbers in range (RAND_MAX; max - min). RAND_MAX is implementation details, but usually equals 7FFF.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `rand` function:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

Quote:

```
A typical way to generate pseudo-random numbers in a determined range using rand is to use the modulo of the returned value by the range span and add the initial value of the range:

( value % 100 ) is in the range 0 to 99
( value % 100 + 1 ) is in the range 1 to 100
( value % 30 + 1985 ) is in the range 1985 to 2014
```

Comment: @Tux-D That was a code snippet copied straight from the cplusplus website so I guess I figured it was the standard way of doing it. I didn't realize it was incorrect or uncommon to do this way, thanks for the info. Because now I'm curious, what exactly is the problem with this method?

Comment: See `Benjamin Lindley` answer above and my associated comments for the pre-C++11 approach. But my comment above was wrong (I miss read your answer). So I will delete it. The website cplusplus.com is OK bit I (and good for quick reference now and then) but I would NOT use it as an authoritative source.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I read the information above and feel I have a better understanding. I would argue that while my answer isn't the best possible answer, it's not NOT useful. But that's your decision and I thank you again for enlightening me. :)

Comment: See: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Answer (score 3):

```
float RandomFloat(float min, float max)
{
    float r = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    return min + r * (max - min);
}
```

Comment: That's not a uniform distribution. Try putting 7 balls into 3 buckets, such that each bucket has the same amount of balls. You're doing exactly the same.

Comment: I actually think its correct, its multiply a range by a number in [0,1]. Can you exmplain further @polkovnikov.ph ?

Comment: @LorenzoBelli Floats are not uniformly distributed over [0, 1], because they have limited precision. Real numbers are.

Comment: Tell me, what's the odds of this algorithm returning `max`?