# How can I generate a random number between 5 and 25 in c++

Tags: c++, random, srand

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate Random numbers uniformly over entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)
>   [C++ random float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float)

How can I generate a random number between 5 and 25 in c++ ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    int number;
    int randomNum;

    srand(time(NULL));

    randomNum = rand();

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Do `rand() % 20` and increment it by 5.

Comment: Even though the OP's question is terribly vague (what does "random" mean?), this answer should at least mention that the resulting distribution is biased.

Comment: First of all, `rand()` is a pseudo random number generator, not a true random number generator so there's a bias right there in the first place. Secondly, you're taking a modulo of a number which has a upper bound that is not a factor of 20 ( look up `MAX_RAND` ). This can't make the output uniformly distributed. I know I should have talked about this in my answer, but looking at the quality of the question, i assumed that he didn't really need the true RNG.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11:

```
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine re;
re.seed(time(NULL)); // or whatever seed
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(5, 25); // 5-25 *inclusive*

int randomNum = uni(re);
```

Or it could just as well be:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d5(1, 5); // 1-5 inclusive
int randomNum = d5(re) + d5(re) + d5(re) + d5(re) + d5(re);
```

which would give a different distribution on the same range.

Comment: +1 Note you can also use boost if your compiler does not yet support C++11.

Comment: @KillianDS: Or even `<tr1/random>` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way:

```
#include <random>

typedef std::mt19937 rng_type; // pick your favourite (i.e. this one)
std::uniform_int_distribution<rng_type::result_type> udist(5, 25);

rng_type rng;

int main()
{
  // seed rng first!

  rng_type::result_type random_number = udist(rng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    int number;
    int randomNum;

    srand(time(NULL));

    number = rand() % 20;
cout << (number) << endl;

}
```