# C - Random numbers between 10 and 30

Tags: c, random, numbers

I have `polje[i]=rand()%30+1;` for random between 1-30, but how can I make it so it's between 10 and 30?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number from within a range - C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range-c) and of [Generate random numbers uniformly over entire range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)

Comment: little late but the simplest answer is int random = arc4random_uniform(20) + 10;

Answer (score 5):

```
polje[i]=rand()%21+10;
```

The %21, gives you a number between 0 and 20. Adding 10, gives you a number between 10 and 30.

Tricky question...Hope that helps...

Comment: Another way to clarify would be that `21 = (30-10)+1` and `+10` signifies the starting number.  So you could have `min = 10; max = 30; range = max - min; polje[i] = rand() % (range + 1) + min;`

Answer (score 1):

How about using **rand()%20+11?** With this you can generate random numbers from 10 to 29. Dint this work? Or try **rand()%21+10** This one will be include 30 too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try rand()%21+10;

the answer is in the range of (10,30)