# C++ Random String Array not working?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
string quotes[2];
        quotes[0] = "This is number one";
        quotes[1] = "this is two";
        quotes[2] = "and three";

            cout << quotes[rand() % 2] << " " << endl;
            cout << endl;
```

Hi guys,

I'm trying to make it so a random string in the array prints out.

I'm very new to c++ and this looks correct to me. But when run, I get 1 and then 0 display?

Comment: `quotes` has size `2`, yet you access three elements. That is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Also, you never get #2 because your `rand()` can only return 0 or 1.

Comment: @Jongware, You mean `rand() % 2` can only result in 0 or 1.

Comment: Accept an answer to rescue from downvotes, quick!!! ;) ...

Comment: you need to seed the random number generator.  If you don't you very well may get the same stream of numbers over and over.  Note that if you use `srand(time(NULL))` to seed it and you run it twice in the same second you will get the same answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your array set to contain 2 elements but assign it 3 elements. In addition you have rand() generating 2 values (0, and 1) instead of the needed three values. (0, 1, and 2) I am unsure if this is a problem for you but the rand() isn't seeded and thus it will generate the same order of numbers each time. A possible revision of your code is below:

```
#include <ctime>
string quotes[3];
    quotes[0] = "This is number one";
    quotes[1] = "this is two";
    quotes[2] = "and three";
srand(time(NULL)); //Seed the rand();
        cout << quotes[rand() % 3] << " " << endl;
        cout << endl;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked and it comes up different each time! Genius

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your array does not have enough space:

```
string quotes[2];
```

means the valid indexes are `0` and `1`. Index `2` is past the end of the array.

When you intend to initialize all elements of an array, you can skip its dimension, like this:

```
string quotes[] = {
    "This is number one"
,   "this is two"
,   "and three"
};
```

In addition, if you would like to get a random number between 0 and 2, inclusive, use `%3` instead of `%2`:

```
cout << quotes[rand() % 3] << " " << endl;
cout << endl;
```

Comment: I just did this and now it prints [1] twice? any ideas

Comment: @user3084666 There is no guarantee that a particular random number is going to come up. Run this, say, 30 times, and you should see a decent distribution of prints among the three choices.

Comment: Sorry, I mean't it littrally prints [1] twice at the same time. So

this is two
this is two

Comment: Thats impossible (with the code you posted)

Comment: @user3084666 Please show the complete code that does the printing then. This code works fine on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/uGrDbv)).

Comment: In fact, with the default seed of 1, it's guaranteed to work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You declare string quotes[2], string quotes[2] will be out of the array range.It should string quotes[3]  or you just comment //quotes[2] = "and three"; because rand()%2 will never access quotes[2].

Answer (score 1):

declare your array to have 3 elements

```
string quotes[3];
```

and also change your indexer to have the posibility of hitting all 3 elements

```
...quotes[rand() % 3]...
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm very new to c++ and this looks correct to me.

Ok, so let me tell you something: in C++ we don't use C style arrays. Period. If you really want fixed sized arrays use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If you want something more dynamic: use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If you want fixed size array of `bool`, use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), and if you want it dynamic, use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

> But when run, I get 1 and then 0 display?

Of course you do. The `%` (modulus) operator will return the remainder of the division between the left and right hand side. For example: `3 % 2 = 1` and `2 % 2 = 0`. In your example, since `2 % 2 = 0`, `rand() % 2` will always return either `0` or `1` (never `2`); which is perfect, since your array only contains 2 elements of index `0` and `1`.

If what you meant is to have an array until the `2`nd index, then you meant to declare an array of 3 items:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> quotes;
```

and then define the "randomizer" to:

```
std::cout << quotes[rand() % 3] << " " << std::endl;
```

---

Also, please, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20136256/493122) that will point to you to the flaws of using `rand()` with the modulus operator, and how to fix them.

Comment: *in C++ we don't use C style arrays. Period.* If only I could say this were true. Anyway, if using `std::array`, might as well use `<random>`.

Comment: @chris, hope is the last thing to die.