# rand() Function not Working in Conjunction with File I/O

Tags: c++, loops, random

I am making a program to configure my wifi as I move to and from different networks frequently. I am generating a random number to be the last number in the sequence of 192.168.0.*. Now when I run the code without the file i/o the random number generates just fine, however, when I run it with the file i/o it only generates 2 or 144. Could someone tell me why this is happening and perhaps offer a solution. Thanks. Below is the code that generates the random number and checks it against the previous number used.

```
//initialise variables so rndm>2 and <253
int rndm, minNum=2, maxNum=253, iHistory;
bool loop=0;


while(loop==0){
  std::cout<<"One Moment please, generating random number...\n";
  //generate random number
  rndm = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX+1)) * (maxNum-minNum+1) + minNum;

  //Read number from history file
  ifstream inputFile("History.txt");
  string line;

  while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
      istringstream ss(line);
      string history;
      ss >> history ;
      iHistory=atoi(history.c_str());
      //If random number was used before, loop
      if(iHistory==rndm){  
          loop=0;
      }
      else{
          loop=1;            //else continue
      }
   }
}
//Write random number to file
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("History.txt");
myfile << rndm;
myfile.close();

std::cout<<"Random number is: "<<rndm<<"\n\n";
```

Comment: For each of your tests, how many times does it output "One moment please..."?  When "it generates just fine without the file i/o", does it always generate the same number?  When you say "it generates 2 or 144 each time", if you remove History.txt, is it always the same, but the next time it's always the other?  The scanty evidence you provided makes me think you need a good ol' `srand(time(0))` in your initialization. `rand()` isn't random - it just goes through a sequence of predetermined numbers based on the random seed.  If you don't seed the generator, you always get the same results.

Comment: It will run through that twice if 2 was used before, and it will then generate 144. When I delete History.txt the process repeats itself. I don't quite get what you're talking about with seeding the process, as it works with the seed if the file i/o is removed.

Comment: If you remove the file i/o, it always generates 2, doesn't it?  Look up `srand` to understand seeding.

Comment: Try adding srand(time(NULL)) before your loop.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It actually generated random numbers just fine **before** I added the file i/o, it was adding it that caused the problems. I added `srand (time(0))` before the while loop and it seems to be working now. One question however, I still don't understand why adding the file i/o would have made this require a seed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, I just changed the random number generator.

```
int min = 2;
int max = 253;
int rng = 0;
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

rng = rand() % max;
if(rng == min-1 || rng == max-1){ rng++; }
```

Make sure you read up on seeds.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The particular formula I was using to generate my random number was from a post on rand() that you find found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range/288869#288869