# How can I get a uniformly distributed random number from the interval [0, 1] in C++?

Tags: c++

How can I get a uniformly distributed random number from the interval [0, 1]?

I am currently using the following code, but it is in C and I would like to know how one does things in C++ instead.

```
double RND()
{
    return ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
}
```

Comment: Even though one reads `rand()/RAND_MAX` a lot, it still is not uniform.

Comment: 1. What makes you think that wouldn't work for C++?

Comment: I want to find a uniform random. I used above code to generate that number. However, it is better if I create a C++ function

Comment: Use the random number library in C++11. Mersenne twister is a good starting point.

Comment: This type of baseline function would be left as-is in C++.  If you want to convert it to a method, then you are going to need to define a class to hold that function.  If you already have a class that needs this method, just change the function statement line so its a member function of your existing class.

Comment: Yes, I am using VC11 lib #include<random>. Could you suggest me one way? I only find the uniform integer number example

Comment: It's all in the docs. But the fact that you want to *include* 1 makes it a little more interesting: the new libraries do allow that though.

Comment: Check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20136256](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20136256) I think you will find it useful

Answer (score 4):

This is actually somewhat tricky to do correctly. For integers, the uniform distribution class produces numbers in the range [min...max], but for real numbers, the range is [min ... max). To get [0 .. 1.0], we need to add a small number to the upper end of the range. As it happens, since our number is 1.0, the standard library gives us exactly the correct number to add as the `epsilon()` for the target type:

```
std::mt19937_64 gen{ std::random_device()() };
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis{
    0.0,
    1.0 + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
};
```

`epsilon` is the smallest number that can be added to 1.0 and produce a result that compares greater than 1.0, so this allows numbers up to (and including) 1.0, but *no* greater--precisely the requested range.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `<random>` library added in C++11. See [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) for more information on distribution and different RNGs.

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,1.0);
double number = distribution(generator);
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Captain Giraffe, above code will be for the range [0,1) and not [0,1]. Use T.C.'s suggested `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,std::nextafter(1.0, 2.0));` to get a closed upper bound.

Comment: From the docs *"uniformly distributed on the interval [a, b),"*.  I.e. excluding b.

Comment: For a closed interval, use `std::nextafter(1.0, 2.0)` as the upperbound.

Comment: It is only [0 1). But I need the range [0 1]

Comment: Yes, use T.C. answer. `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.0,std::nextafter(1.0, 2.0));`