# Generating discrete uniform distribution in C

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to generate a discrete uniform distribution in C between 0 and 1.

Normally you'd expect: t = rand()%2 , but it seems there is a problem with this approach (it seems to be related to lower bits having more probabilities, although I don't really understand much about that).

I tried a trick that I found somewhere on the Internet:

Let t1,t2 be 2 not so uniform distributions between 0 and 1 with probability p for 1, (1-p) for p. Then we take 2 random numbers:

```
t1 : p for 1, (1-p) for 0

t2 : p for 1, (1-p) for 0
```

If t1!=t2 we have the probability for (t1,t2)=(1,0) and (t1,t2) = (0,1) to be the same: p(1-p). So we just the repeat the sampling until we get t1!=t2 and we choose the random number t = t1 (it really doesn't matter). Here is my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
/*
Declare variable to hold seconds on clock.
*/
int i,t1,t2,t;
time_t seconds;
seconds = time(NULL);

/*
Get value from system clock and
place in seconds variable.
*/
time(&seconds);
/*
Convert seconds to a unsigned
integer.
*/
srand((unsigned int) seconds);
/*
Output random values.
*/
    for (i =0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        do
        {
            t1 = rand()%2;
            t2 = rand()%2;
        }
        while (t1==t2);
        t = t1;

        printf("%d\n",t);
    }
            /*printf("%d",rand()%2);
    printf("%d",rand()%2);*/

return 0;
}
```

Am I right or wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: You're going to need to understand what's actually wrong with `rand` to understand why this can't possibly work (it's nothing to do with the distribution), but basically: don't use `rand`.

Comment: A simple alternative to `rand()%2` that doesn't suffer from bias due to low-entropy in the lowest bit is `rand() > RAND_MAX / 2`.

Comment: So by "discrete uniform distribution between 0 and 1", you mean simply 0 with probability 1/2 and 1 with probability 1/2?

Answer (score 2):

Never use `rand()`. Use `random()` or even better, a [generator from the PCG family](http://www.pcg-random.org/).

For either one, all of the provided bits are good individually.  `random()` provides 31 random bits. Use all of them instead of just one. There's no point in throwing away the other 30.  E.g.

```
static inline int random_bit(void)
{
    static long val;
    static int bits = 0;
    int bit;

    if (bits == 0) {
        val = random();
        bits = 31;
    }
    bit = val & 1;
    val >>= 1;
    bits--;
    return bit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your solution. Can you explain it in more details? Thank you very much

Comment: No, not really. It is rather straightforward. You should simply study the code.

Comment: I will give it a try then

Answer (score 0):

The built-in random number generator `rand()` isn't guaranteed to have a particular distribution as you assumed (probability of 'p' and '1-p'). Although `rand() > RAND_MAX / 2` is better, it still may not be having a particular distribution. It is better to use any other method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range).

Having said that, if you assumed that the probability of 1 and 0 are 'p' and '1-p' for your random number generator, then what you have done to generate uniform distribution looks mathematically correct with probability of `2*p*(1-p)` for each of 1 and 0, although you wouldn't be willing to use this as you indicated in comments.

Comment: OK, I will find another function for this. But if p is large (about 0.9) wouldn't the while loop be less likely to break (because the probability of t1 =t2=1 would be 0.9*09 much larger than when they are different ) I'm just guessing :P

Comment: @TruongTroll, you are right. If you assume that p is 1, then p(1-p) is 0, and the loop never breaks. But still mathematically, your solution is a uniform random generator with each outcome having a probability of 0 :-).