# Picking random lattice points in (x,y) plane

Tags: c++, random, lattice

I'm trying to find a way of choosing random lattice points in an `x`,`y` plane. It is suggested that I use the following code:

```
//////////////////////
// Pick random site //
////////////////////// 
int m=int(rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX*L*L);
int mx=m%L; //x coordinate of m site
int my=int(m*1.0/L); // y coordinate of m site
```

In other words: `m` is a random integer between `0` and `L^2`. The `x` coordinate is m mod L, which is a number between `0` and `L`. `y` is set as the closest integer to `m/L`, which is an integer between `0` and `L`.

It seems to work, but in `L^2` runs, are we more likely to search one part of the `x`,`y` system than another? Could anyone explain why, and whether there is an alternative method for picking random coordinate points in on an `x`,`y` plane that sampled the space uniformly?

Comment: Read this: [Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288739/691711)

Comment: You'll probably find some better random number generators with control over distribution propabilities looking at the [standard c++ random number facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) than the primitive `std::rand()` function.

Comment: Well, other than the remarks in the previous comments, It depends on your definition of "uniformly sampled", I guess. Is [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l9Uad5cmCfMCvACq) close enough?

Comment: Many thanks team.  @Bob__: really great of you to code that. Brilliantly visualised!

Answer (score 0):

try to research pseudo generator [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), which is available from C++11.
Hope this helps you.

Also look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) for documentation.

Here is how you can use it for uniform distribution:

```
    int ran_num(const int start, const int stop)
    {
        random_device rd;
        mt19937 mt(rd());
        uniform_int_distribution dist(start, stop);

        return dist(mt);
   }
```

Hope this is somehow helpful!