# How to generate four independent nonrepeatable random int32s in C++?

Tags: c++11, random

Normally people use the computer's clock. For example:

int timeSec = time(0)

But I need 4 independent non-repeatable ints, generated pretty much simulateously.

Comment: The clock is generally used to seed the random number generator, not as the random number itself. Information on random number generation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 0):

You could find it here if you avoid the range and check if your number is not repeated:

[Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-an-entire-range)